# How do I subset data set with specific condition?

Tags: dataset

I have a dataset that has ages of children. I want to subset the variables that correspond to a certain bracket of age.

basically if I have a dataset

```
data = names  age  marks  attendance
        A      5     1       90
        B      12    9       87
        C      16    7       98
        D      3     0       70
        E      7     4       77
```

I want this:

```
df = names  age (2-10) marks attendance
       A       5         1       90
       D       3         0       70
       E       7         4       77
```

And similarly for the age bracket 11-16

Comment: How is the dataset stored? and what language do you use? SQL? Python+Pandas? ...?

Comment: Data is stored in csv and I use only R for data analysis mostly.